# How to get the annotations of concepts (annotations on class IRIs) with OWLAPI?

Tags: java, annotations, ontology, owl-api

In the pato.owl ontology on the website http://www.obofoundry.org/, some concepts has more than one Annotation. For example, concept PATO_0001051 has Label "acute angle to" and the definition: "An angle which is less than 90 degrees". How can I get through owlapi this Definition? Many thanks.

```
    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/PATO_0001051">
       <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">acute angle to</rdfs:label>
       <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/PATO_0002326"/>
       <obo:IAO_0000115 rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">An angle which is less than 90 degrees.</obo:IAO_0000115>
       <oboInOwl:id rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">PATO:0001051</oboInOwl:id>
       <oboInOwl:hasOBONamespace rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">quality</oboInOwl:hasOBONamespace>
       <oboInOwl:inSubset rdf:resource="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/pato#relational_slim"/>
       <oboInOwl:inSubset rdf:resource="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/pato#value_slim"/>
   </owl:Class>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear Artemis and Ignazio, thank you very much for your answers.  Here is the answer:

```
    for(OWLClass owl_class : localOntology.getClassesInSignature(true)){
         for(OWLAnnotationAssertionAxiom annotations:owl_class.getAnnotationAssertionAxioms(localOntology))
             if(annotations.getProperty().getIRI().getFragment()==null) {
                            System.out.println("definition: "+annotations.getValue());
                                                                        }
                                                         }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this, is to find the class that you are looking for and then extract all the annotations that relate to that specific class. Remember that OWLAPI is quite well written and you can extract the string form of most of the IRIs. This is the way I have written it:

```
        for(OWLClass owl_class : localOntology.getClassesInSignature(true)){

        if(owl_class.getIRI().getFragment().equalsIgnoreCase("PATO_0001051"))
            for(OWLAnnotationAssertionAxiom annotations:owl_class.getAnnotationAssertionAxioms(localOntology))
                System.out.println(annotations.getProperty().getIRI().getFragment()+ " "+ annotations.getValue());
    }
```

The result looks like:

[image]

Comment: On behalf of the OWLAPI developers, thank you for the compliment :-)

Comment: if the IRI you are after is known, like in this case, there is no need to make string comparisons.

`IRI pato=IRI.create("http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/PATO_0001051");`
`for(OWLAnnotationAssertionAxiom annotations:localOntology.getAnnotationAssertionAxioms(pato))`
`System.out.println(annotations.getProperty().getIRI().getFragment()+ " "+ annotations.getValue());`

This will work with OWLAPI 3.x and 4.x

Comment: I want to read the Definition of each concept in this ontology not only PATO_0001051. The type of this annotation is not clear to me. Therefore I cannot use instanceOf. As I wanted to read the lables I wrote:                                                                                                                       if (owlAnnotationAssertionAxiom.getValue() instanceof OWLLiteral)                                                                                              but in this case I do not know what the type is.

Comment: This code that I've written doesn't depend on the type, it gets them all out. See the image.The first part `annotations.getProperty().getIRI().getFragment()` give you the type, the second part the value. If you want all the classes, just take the filter out. The filter is there to display the solution for only one concept. What is the question here exactly?